# How can I assign numbers to characters in a string numerically without an array in Java?

Tags: java, string, character, assign, numerical

So we haven't learned arrays yet in class, but we have an assignment that requires us to assign numerical values to letters. At least, we aren't told we need this, but that's the only way I can think of doing it. (Encrypting a string through shifting characters a specific way). I don't mean assign the same value for the same letter, I mean in like a "abba" string, it changes to "0123".

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to ask a specific question rather than just 'how do I solve the problem I've been assigned'. Show what you've tried so far and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option then would be to use a loop. For example:

```
String str = "abba";
String numbers = "";


for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
   numbers = numbers + Integer.toString(i);
}
```

This way you will go through each character in `str` and you will create a new string of numbers with the index of each character in `str`. The result for `numbers` will be "0123" just as you requested.